# ColdFusion Office 365 Exchange distribution group access?

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, office365

I am currently using cfexchangeConnection in order to connect to our outlook.office365.com connection.

My goal is to connect a user, find out what distribution group they are in (e.g., Staff, Members, Clerks, ...), and then send them to the appropriate web page, depending on their group.

I've looked at and played around with cfexchangeContact, but the best I could come up with is a list of that person's contacts.

We have a 'global' address book throughout our company, but I have no idea how to access it.

**Edit:**
The code I use to contact Exchange is as follows:

```
<cfexchangeConnection action="open" 
        username ="#username#" 
        password="#password#" 
        server="outlook.office365.com" 
        protocol="https" 
        connection="myConnection" 
        serverversion="2010">
```

I used the following code to try get access to the distribution groups, through the global address book with this code:

```
<cfexchangecontact required action = "get" 
        name = "query identifier" 
        optional connection = "connection ID">
```

Alas, this only gets me the contacts, not the address book.

What I would like to get as a result, is whether the person who authenticated through the cfexchangeConnection tag, is a member of one of our distribution groups/global address book group. So far I am thinking of adding another Exchange member, adding the distribution group as a contact, and then using the cfexchangeContact tag to see whether they are in the contact list of this new Exchange member.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code that you have tried, what you got as results, and what you would have wanted?

Comment: The code I use to contact Exchange is as follows:
`<cfexchangeConnection 
        action="open" 
        username ="#username#" 
        password="#password#"
        server="outlook.office365.com" 
        protocol="https"
        connection="myConnection"
        serverversion="2010">`

I used the following code to try get access to the distribution groups, through the global address book with this code:
`<cfexchangecontact
    required
    action = "get"
    name = "query identifier"
    optional
    connection = "connection ID">`

Alas, this only gets me the contacts, not the address book.

Comment: What I would like to get as a result, is whether the person who authenticated through the cfexchangeConnection tag, is a member of one of our distribution groups/global address book group. So far I am thinking of adding another Exchange member, adding the distribution group as a contact, and then using the cfexchangeContact tag to see whether they are in the contact list of this new Exchange member.

Comment: @AcePlayer - Not everyone reads the comments. Those kinds of details belong in the question. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27491454/edit) to include the additional info. Then delete the redundant comments.

Comment: To the ppl voting to close: this is a *very good* question, it just needs a code sample. It's there in a comment. Stop voting to close, eh?

Comment: @AcePlayer pls - quickly - edit your question and get a decent code sample in there, and refine your question to ask a more precise question. Otherwise the ppl with no other sense of authority in their lives will continue to try to close you out. And it'll then take 5 of us to reopen it so we can crack on with sorting-out your issue.

Comment: Added the stuff from my phone. On holiday so haven't been checking email. I hope the code section came out in the copy.